# JAX-RS Response validation using schemas

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, jax-rs

I am using Jersey to send and receive XML over a HTTP REST service, while representing the data in JAXB annotated classes. Once I receive a `Response` all I need to do is call `response.readEntity(Foo.class)` in order to unmarshal the response into an instance of `Foo`.

Normally during the JAXB unmarshalling process you can validate the input using `Schema`s, but I didn't find any options to do the same when reading responses into entities.

This is important to us because we have XSD files defining the format of the input and we would like to validate against these schemas. Currently my only idea is to read the `Response` into a `String`, create the `JAXBContext` manually and assign the schema to the `Unmarshaller` before unmarshalling the `String` into an instance of `Foo`. While this doesn't sound all that horrible, hopefully there is a more concise way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the [ValidationEventHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/ValidationEventHandler.html) interface from the JAXB API.

There is a nice blog by [Blaise Doughan](https://plus.google.com/+BlaiseDoughan) describing the workflow [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html?m=1).

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something but isn't ValidationEventHandler purpose is to handle validation events? I would like to tell the unmarshaller what to use in order to validate the data, not what to do when it encounters a validator error (which it won't, without the XSD schema).

Comment: That's explained in the blog. Ignore the suggestion of using a custom event handler if you don't think you need it.

Comment: Yes, but in the blog they assign the `Schema` to the `Unmarshaller`. As I stated in the post I know how to do this. The question is about how to do this with JAX-RS responses.

Comment: Please post your code and point out which part you have a problem with

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the way I solved this is that I read the response into a string and than I manually unmarshalled that into an object. Here is the source code of the function that does this:

```
public static <T> T unmarshal(Response response, Class<T> entityClass, Schema schema) {
  String responseStr = response.readEntity(String.class);
  try {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(entityClass);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
    unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
    try (StringReader responseReader = new StringReader(responseStr)) {
      return (T) unmarshaller.unmarshal(responseReader);
    }
  } catch (JAXBException e) {
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error during response unmarshalling", e);
  }
  return null;
}
```

I consider this to be kind of a hack/workaround, rather than a proper solution, but it works flawlessly.